# How to change modal width of the selectfield in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a dynamic form in a Sencha Touch app and I would like to change the width of the modal window when the user tap in the field or change height of the items in the list because we have items with more characters and I don´t find the property "variableHeights" of the Lists...

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: @MohitSaxena no, currently I don't have news in this topic